# Issue with HttpClient in AEM

Tags: aem, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I have an HttpClient code written that is from **org.apache.commons.httpclient** package.

In that I am setting connection time and socket time out this way.

```
final HttpClient http = new HttpClient(this.connectionManager);

http.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout", this.connectionTimeout);
http.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", this.socketTimeout);
```

Now the Adobe Cloud has raised issue that timeout is not being set(which is not true).
They suggested to set timeouts using

```
@Reference
private HttpClientBuilderFactory httpClientBuilderFactory;

public void doThis() {
  HttpClientBuilder builder = httpClientBuilderFactory.newBuilder();
  RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setConnectTimeout(5000)
    .setSocketTimeout(5000)
    .build();
  builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);

  HttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

  // do something with the client
}
```

Refer [Link](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-cloud-manager/using/how-to-use/custom-code-quality-rules.html)

**But HttpClientBuilderFactory does not belong to **org.apache.commons.httpclient** it belongs to org.apache.http.client**

And always returns Closable Http client.

How do I resolve this security issue? Can I add an annotation for exception? Or will I have to rewrite all my code?

This issue is with Adobe Experience Manager 6.5 instance.

Comment: Do I understand you right, that the Security Checks of Adobes "AEM Managed Services - Build Pipeline" raise an Issue? Btw. my current project also has a lot effort to dance around that system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Adobe has two versions of HttpClient the old 3.x that has package structure org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient and the one that HttpClientBuilderFactory gives out that is 4.x org.apache.http.Httpclient.

I was breaking my head around this. Finally we were left with two options...

1) Rewrite all our commons http api(3.x) to the newer version of apache.http (4.x) that has the methods setTimeout and setConnectionTimeout

OR

2)@SuppressWarnings("CQRules:ConnectionTimeoutMechanism")

We chose Option number 2 as the effort arround this was huge and we are planning to go live soon.

Answer (score 0):

Is it probably because you are not setting the right timeout parameter?

You are setting the property `http.connection.timeout` which is not available in the class `org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams`.

`http.getParams()` returns an instance of [HttpClientParams](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpClientParams.html) which has the socket timeout and connection manager timeout but not a connection timeout. You could probably use the constant `HttpClientParams.CONNECTION_MANAGER_TIMEOUT` to set a timeout for the connection manager?

On the other hand, the property `http.connection.timeout` is available for the class [HttpConnectionParams](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html).

[Constant field values reference](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams.CONNECTION_MANAGER_TIMEOUT)

Comment: Problem was AEM ships two versions on HttpClient and the older version is the one that we were using. See my answer above.